# Can a revived hero contest a point?

Tags: overwatch

When Mercy revives a hero or a group of heroes, if they are on a point, do they immediately begin contesting that point? It's difficult to tell whether it's Mercy herself, or the people she revives.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.

As soon as the hero's model comes back, even while it's glowing yellow, it immediately counts as a player. It will start contesting points, occupy physical space, block bullets and projectiles, and so on, with the only difference of being invulnerable.

Comment: Ugh, that's annoying. It seems a bit overpowered that they can contest in this weird heavenly state, but that answers it. Thanks!

Comment: did this change with the ana buff patch? I've lost so many games when we've had multiple people on the point that have been ressed at the end of overtime, but haven't started contesting.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf nah, it only lasts a second or so (basically to give the player a chance to reorient and possibly seek cover), and if you train your weapon on the yellow silhouette, give it a one-count and start unloading, they don't stay back alive very long. Ults like Pharah's are also good at un-rezzing large groups :D